# Python- How to make an if statement between x and y?

Tags: python, if-statement, between, floating-point-comparison, numeric-ranges

I've recently been breaching out to Python, as C++ is fun and all, but python seems kinda cool.  I want to make Python do something as long as the input is between a certain number range.

```
def main():
    grade = float(input("“What’s your grade?”\n:"))
    if grade >= 90:
        print("“You’re doing great!”")
    elif(78 >= grade <= 89):
        print("“You’re doing good!”")
    elif(77 >= grade > 65):
        print("You need some work")
    else:
        print("Contact your teacher")

main()
```

The problem arises when I'm making the elif statement, I can't make it so Python only prints the "doing great" statement as long as the grade is between 65 and 89.  How would you go about doing ranges of numbers?

Comment: @Frito it's there...

Comment: Heh, sorry. I saw it before you updated :-)

Answer (score 23):

In Python you can do something like this to check whether an variable is within a specific range:

```
if 78 <= grade <= 89:
    pass
```